# Are there minikube args that could be applied to all minikube start calls?

Tags: minikube

I tend to run minikube start with a handful of flags.  Like `--memory` and `--cpus` and `--kubernetes-verison`.  I'd like to specify this in a file and not have to create a shell script that makes this start-up simple and consistent.  Does such a thing already exists in some capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is use `minikube config` to customize the minikube startup.

The command `minikube config` writes a file in `~/.minikube/config/config.json` and you can set options using `miikube config set [OPTION] [VALUE]`.

[Here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/config/#synopsis) you can find a list of available commands.

To set the parameters mentioned in your post, you need to use:

```
minikube config set memory xxx
minikube config set cpus xxx
minikube config set kubernetes-version xxx
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/config/) page to get all options.